# Neural Networks in Keras R: Doubts about improving my analysis and incorporating categorical variables as inputs

Tags: r, keras

I'm a beginner to R, Keras and Neural Networks and this is my first post in Stack Overflow, so I'll try to explain myself in the most professional way I can. I have tried to find information regarding this issue I have but everything I find is in Python and I don't know how to implement it in R.

So, I'm trying to implement a Multi-Class classification problem using the following model utilizing a Softmax Layer output:

```
model <- keras_model_sequential()
model %>%
  layer_dense(units = 512, activation = 'relu', input_shape = 26) %>% 
  layer_dropout(rate = 0.2) %>% 
  layer_batch_normalization() %>%
  layer_dense(units = 256, activation = 'relu') %>%
  layer_dropout(rate = 0.2) %>%  
  layer_batch_normalization() %>%
  layer_dense(units = 256, activation = 'relu') %>%
  layer_dropout(rate = 0.5) %>%   
  layer_dense(units = 5, activation = 'softmax')
```

My data consists in around 35.000 training examples, and I used a 90/10 data split utilizing random sampling. Finally, I fit, evaluated and calculated some predictions to manually check if I did a decent fit, as shown below with some very standard code:

```
# Fit the model
history <- model %>% fit(
  x_train, y_train, 
  epochs = 30, batch_size = 128, 
  validation_split = 0.2
)

# Evaluate the model
score <- model %>% evaluate(x_test, y_test, batch_size = 128)
print(score)
```

Nevertheless, I keep on getting low per-class-precision on the Softmax layer, which is why I'd like to make my model more precise.Hence, my questions are as follows:

- How can I implement quickly and systematic **hyperparameter regularization** (#layers, #nodes, learning rate, early stopping, etc.) on Keras in R (e.g. random grid search)? I read that the **caret package** can work, but I'm a bit lost on how to use this or other packages with keras.
- How can I add **categorical variables** as inputs for my model? Think that my data is arranged as an n x m matrix, where the first  k < m columns are categorical variables.

Also, any other recommendations to improve my model are highly appreciated!